# android publish app on google play optimization tips (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion)

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, apk, publishing

I am trying to publish my app on google play store. I have designed it for phones as well as for tabs on Android Gingerbread(2.3.3) . But I am coming across some optimization tips. I know this question has been discussed earlier too but I am unable find a solution. Please help me out. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of google play developer console]

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: what optimization tip is shown to you?

Comment: tips that - Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets

Comment: and another tip - The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making mistake on your android manifest:

1. Your android min version is set to 8, but Initial support for tablets was added in Android 3.0 (API level 11). So it must be 11 or higher.
2. Under uses-feature and uses-permission, you're requiring some hardware features that maybe not available on some tablet like front camera or telephony. For all this kind of features,  you should add a new parameter `android:required="false"`

Here is the soure with more details from android developper website.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#hardware-requirements

Comment: hey but i require to use camera through intent!

Comment: Ok, but not all tablet have the camera, what you have to do is to make your application works normally when the camera is not available, and  offer "graceful degradation" and alternative functionality where appropriate or display a dialog to say the user he needs a camera.

Comment: ok i did that. put the features as false.. but still the same

Comment: Can you tell me the remaining items you see under the tab (TODO - desing your app for tablet) the one, we can see on your screenshot.

Comment: No there were no more items.. just two of them. Resolved! thanks to u :)

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an app, the Developer Console now runs a series of checks to verify basic criteria from the Tablet App Quality Checklist and shows you any issues it finds in the Optimization Tips page.


For ideas on how to design and build a great tablet app, including details on how to address issues listed in your Optimization Tips page, check out the [Tablet App Quality Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html). Remember that a great tablet experience goes well beyond these basic checks. Keep working to bring your tablet users the most polished UI and richest content possible